# Multiple scrollable tabs on one page

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

After going through a YouTube tutorial on how to create scrollable tabs, I have successfully managed to do so while incorporating Bootstrap 5. However, I'm having difficulty getting multiple scrollable tabs to work on one page. While the tabs and tab-content work correctly, I can only get the arrow buttons to work for the initial scrollable tabs.

Here's the code:

```
const tabsBox = document.querySelector(".tabs-box"),
allTabs = tabsBox.querySelectorAll(".scroll-tab"),
arrowIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow-icon i");

let isDragging = false;

const handleIcons = (scrollVal) => {
    let maxScrollableWidth = tabsBox.scrollWidth - tabsBox.clientWidth;
    arrowIcons[0].parentElement.style.display = scrollVal <= 0 ? "none" : "flex";
    arrowIcons[1].parentElement.style.display = maxScrollableWidth - scrollVal <= 1 ? "none" : "flex";
}

arrowIcons.forEach(icon => {
    icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // if clicked icon is left, reduce 200 from tabsBox scrollLeft else add
        let scrollWidth = tabsBox.scrollLeft += icon.id === "left" ? -200 : 200;
        handleIcons(scrollWidth);
    });
});

allTabs.forEach(tab => {
    tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
        tabsBox.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
        tab.classList.add("active");
    });
});

const dragg = (e) => {
    if(!isDragg) return;
    tabsBox.classList.add("dragging");
    tabsBox.scrollLeft -= e.movementX;
    handleIcons(tabsBox.scrollLeft)
}

const dragStop = () => {
    isDragg = false;
    tabsBox.classList.remove("dragging");
}

tabsBox.addEventListener("mousedown", () => isDragg = true);
tabsBox.addEventListener("mousemove", dragg);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", dragStop);
```

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-width: 1200px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.wrapper .arrow-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow-icon:first-child {
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 20%, transparent);
}

.arrow-icon:last-child {
  right: 0;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff 20%, transparent);
}

.arrow-icon i {
  width: 24px;
  height: 38px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.arrow-icon i:hover {
  color: #00f;
}

.arrow-icon:first-child i {
  margin-left: -7px;
}

.arrow-icon:last-child i {
  margin-right: -6px;
}

.wrapper .tabs-box {
  display: flex;
  gap: 12px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs-box.dragging {
  scroll-behavior: auto;
  cursor: grab;
}

.tabs-box .scroll-tab {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.tabs-box .scroll-tab:hover {
  background: #666;
  color: #000;
}

.tabs-box.dragging .scroll-tab {
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tabs-box .scroll-tab.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #5372F0;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arrow-icon"><i id="left" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i></div>
  <ul class="tabs-box nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist" style="flex-wrap: nowrap;border-bottom:none;">
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab active" id="tab1-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab1" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-selected="true" style="text-align: center;">Information</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="tab2-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab2" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2" aria-selected="false">Products</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="tab3-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab3" role="tab" aria-controls="tab3" aria-selected="false">Podcasts</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="tab4-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab4" role="tab" aria-controls="tab4" aria-selected="false">Databases</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="tab5-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab5" role="tab" aria-controls="tab5" aria-selected="false">Web Development</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="tab6-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab6" role="tab" aria-controls="tab6" aria-selected="false">Unboxing</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="arrow-icon"><i id="right" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i></div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active show mt-2" id="tab1" aria-labelledby="tab1-tab">This is the content of Tabulation Link 1...
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="tab2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab2-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 2... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="tab3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab3-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 3... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="tab4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab4-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 4... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="tab5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab5-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 5... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="tab6" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab6-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 6... </div>
</div><br><br>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arrow-icon"><i id="left2" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i></div>
  <ul class="tabs-box nav nav-tabs" id="myTab2" role="tablist" style="flex-wrap: nowrap;border-bottom:none;">
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab active" id="ytab1-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ytab1" role="tab" aria-controls="ytab1" aria-selected="true" style="text-align: center;">Requests</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="ytab2-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ytab2" role="tab" aria-controls="ytab2" aria-selected="false">Contacts</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="ytab3-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ytab3" role="tab" aria-controls="ytab3" aria-selected="false">Resources</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="ytab4-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ytab4" role="tab" aria-controls="ytab4" aria-selected="false">Settings</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="ytab5-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ytab5" role="tab" aria-controls="ytab5" aria-selected="false">Subscriptions</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="ytab6-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ytab6" role="tab" aria-controls="ytab6" aria-selected="false">Social Media</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="arrow-icon"><i id="right2" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i></div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent2">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active show mt-2" id="ytab1" aria-labelledby="ytab1-tab">This is the content of Tabulation Link 1a...
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="ytab2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ytab2-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 2a... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="ytab3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ytab3-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 3a... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="ytab4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ytab4-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 4a... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="ytab5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ytab5-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 5a... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="ytab6" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ytab6-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 6a... </div>
</div><br><br>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arrow-icon"><i id="left3" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i></div>
  <ul class="tabs-box nav nav-tabs" id="mztab3" role="tablist" style="flex-wrap: nowrap;border-bottom:none;">
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab active" id="ztab1-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ztab1" role="tab" aria-controls="ztab1" aria-selected="true" style="text-align: center;">Symbols</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="ztab2-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ztab2" role="tab" aria-controls="ztab2" aria-selected="false">Modifications</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="ztab3-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ztab3" role="tab" aria-controls="ztab3" aria-selected="false">Improvements</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="ztab4-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ztab4" role="tab" aria-controls="ztab4" aria-selected="false">Transactions</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="ztab5-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ztab5" role="tab" aria-controls="ztab5" aria-selected="false">Lyrics</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="ztab6-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#ztab6" role="tab" aria-controls="ztab6" aria-selected="false">Payment</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="arrow-icon"><i id="right3" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i></div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="mztabContent3">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active show mt-2" id="ztab1" aria-labelledby="ztab1-tab">This is the content of Tabulation Link 1b...
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="ztab2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ztab2-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 2b... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="ztab3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ztab3-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 3b... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="ztab4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ztab4-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 4b... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="ztab5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ztab5-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 5b... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="ztab6" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ztab6-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 6b... </div>
</div><br><br>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arrow-icon"><i id="left4" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i></div>
  <ul class="tabs-box nav nav-tabs" id="mwtab4" role="tablist" style="flex-wrap: nowrap;border-bottom:none;">
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab active" id="wtab1-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#wtab1" role="tab" aria-controls="wtab1" aria-selected="true" style="text-align: center;">Proposals</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="wtab2-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#wtab2" role="tab" aria-controls="wtab2" aria-selected="false">Abstract</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="wtab3-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#wtab3" role="tab" aria-controls="wtab3" aria-selected="false">Workaround</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="wtab4-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#wtab4" role="tab" aria-controls="wtab4" aria-selected="false">Compromise</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="wtab5-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#wtab5" role="tab" aria-controls="wtab5" aria-selected="false">Groups</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="scroll-tab" id="wtab6-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#wtab6" role="tab" aria-controls="wtab6" aria-selected="false">Domains</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="arrow-icon"><i id="right4" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i></div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="mwtabContent4">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active show mt-2" id="wtab1" aria-labelledby="wtab1-tab">This is the content of Tabulation Link 1c...
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="wtab2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="wtab2-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 2c... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="wtab3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="wtab3-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 3c... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="wtab4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="wtab4-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 4c... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="wtab5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="wtab5-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 5c... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade mt-2" id="wtab6" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="wtab6-tab"> This is the content of Tabulation Link 6c... </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/za8b20tw/2/) showing the problem

Comment: The `handleIcons` method only adjusts parent of the first two arrows. The code needs to respond to the second set of arrows by adjusting the other tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with the 1st line of your code.

```
const tabsBox = document.querySelector(".tabs-box"),
```

Normally the querySelector return the 1st element which matches the class name ".tab-box". Hence your 1st one is working fine. But, other .tabs-box icon click is not being triggered since it is not selected.
So, you should add something like :

```
const tabsBox = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs-box")
```

Which returns the array of the tabs element and put the logic of loop in it considering your tabsBox is an array.